# How to use QR-Decomposition to reduce the dimension of a dataset?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, machine-learning, dimension-reduction

Let `A` be a matrix of dimension m×n, representing the original data set.

The [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition), `[Q, R] = qr (A)` produces:

- Upper triangular matrix `R` of the same dimension as `A`
- Unitary matrix `Q`

so that `A = Q*R`

If `[m, n] = size (A)`, then

`Q` is `m-by-m` and

`R` is `m-by-n`

How can I use QR-Decomposition to reduce the dimension (reduce the number of columns or features) of `A`?

Comment: @Matt yes I did, but I could not find the answer, I found many articles they use singular Value decomposition (SVD) with QR-decomposition, but I do not what to use SVD.

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer because I'm not sure of what you are asking for, however the tool you might need is the LQ decomposition. Given an **A** matrix with many columns, compute `L = triu(qr(A'))';`. Then `L` will contain the *condensed* information.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for rank reduction you should prefer to use the singular value decomposition unless you know that the original matrix is indeed rank deficient. This is because the svd orders the singular values, whereas the QR decomposition does not.

Nonetheless, I would suggest you try a simple example. If a matrix A is mxn with a rank of p